# Were there any named, blue beverages in the original Star Trek series?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

After seeing an article about the recently marketed Spanish "blue wine" ([here](http://www.bbc.com/travel/story/20161104-the-worlds-first-blue-wine)) I was reminded of *Star Trek TOS* — I am sure I remember a decanter and tumbler with a blue beverage at least once, but I have no idea when.

Neither *Saurian Brandy* nor *Tranya* were blue (based on a quick search only), and that's all I can remember of named TOS beverages.

I'm looking for an episode/scene or some reference to a blue beverage in TOS, and particularly if it was named or described, rather than just incidental.

**note 1:** please limit references to the strict interpretation of TOS tag:

> *Star Trek: The Original Series* is an American science fiction television series created by Gene Roddenberry running from September 8, 1966, through June 3, 1969.

Thanks!

**note 2:** It seems 21st century blue wine is [having issues](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p04w4g0d), let's hope they are ironed out by the 23rd.

Comment: I've [asked on meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10351/19561) if [tag:star-trek-tos] should include the films.

Comment: If the question is about props used in the original TV show sets, then we should only include the TV shows. If the question is about blue alcohol existing canonically within the Kirk era then it includes the movies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Antarean brandy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Antarean_brandy) is a blue alcoholic beverage that was served aboard the *Enterprise* in the Original Series episode, “[Is There in Truth No Beauty?](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Is_There_in_Truth_No_Beauty%3F_(episode))”

[image: Antarean brandy]

Romulans were seen drinking an unnamed blue beverage in “[The Enterprise Incident](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Enterprise_Incident_(episode)).” Memory Alpha makes no comment on whether this beverage could have been [Romulan ale](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Romulan_ale).

Comment: Great! Very nice, very blue, and veryTOS too!

Comment: @uhoh I’ve done a careful-but-not-exhaustive search of Memory Alpha, and I’m fairly sure that these are the only two blue beverages that the site mentions that appear in TOS.

Comment: OK, thanks for the edit and additional info!

Answer (score 3):

[image: Glasses of Romulan Ale being poured]

Romulan Ale is blue.

One of the first instances of seeing it is from *The Wrath of Khan*

> Admiral James T. Kirk received a bottle of Romulan ale, dated 2283, as a birthday gift from Doctor Leonard McCoy in 2285. (Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan) [MEMORY ALPHA](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Romulan_ale)

Comment: Thanks - but isn't that from a movie? I've asked about TOS.

Comment: @uhoh Wrath of Khan is a TOS movie.

Comment: What is a TOS movie? I thought the "S" stands for "Series" as in TV Series.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series

Comment: @uhoh the first 6 movies are by the cast of TOS, and they fall under the TOS tag.

Comment: Actually I do not see any mention of six feature films in the definition of the tag. It does mention following series and moves, but not include. "*Star Trek: The Original Series is an American science fiction television series created by Gene Roddenberry running from September 8, 1966, through June 3, 1969. It has acquired the retronym of Star Trek: The Original Series (Star Trek: TOS or TOS). The show became a cult classic in broadcast syndication during the 1970s, leading to five additional television series, 11 theatrical films (& counting), and numerous books, games, and other products*."

Comment: The [tag:star-trek-tos] tag is for the series, not the films.

Comment: @amaranth  whats the film tag

Comment: There are lots of them: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/star-trek/info

Comment: Think you're taking the whole tagging too serious here. I certainly can't speak for others, but for me "TOS" essentially means (classic) Kirk era, whereas TNG would be Picard. So (at least for me) the first movies somewhat fit into this. I think we could assume the original beverage from the actual series might have been Romulan Ale, as mentioned in the other answer. I wouldn't consider this answer wrong or off-topic as-is, it's more like a good addition to the other one.

Comment: @Mario the tags matter less than the use of TOS in the question title and thrice in the text. Nevertheless, everywhere I look - in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series), in [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series) and yes in the [tag definition](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/star-trek-tos/info) TOS means The Original Series - as filmed and shown on Television by CBS in the US between 1966 and 1969.

Comment: I've [asked on meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10351/19561) if [tag:star-trek-tos] should include the films.

Comment: I just realized you have indeed found an image of an actual "tumbler with a blue beverage" even though I forgot the `tumbler` tag. +1  :)

Answer (score 1):

I am including a photo from memory-alpha.wiki showing Dr McCoy and Kirk drinking from 2 cobalt blue crystal glasses and also another photo of McCoy & spock sharing Saurian brandy in the same glasses.

[image: Spock & McCoy Saurian Brandy Blue crystal glasses]

[image]

Comment: Although the beverage itelf isn't blue - this might indeed be the source of my vague recollection of blue + glass + drink. Thanks!